# Integrating ML Model in Xcode's Swift Playgrounds App

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swift-playground, coreml

So I am using Xcode Swift Playground App. In which I want to add my two MLModels (Validator and Classifier).

At first, I created a dummy xcode project and I copied the Swift Model Class file. But still, I am getting this error in bundle.url

[image: Click Here]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are force-unwrapping a variable (which is not a very good practice).

The force-unwrapping is failing, because there is not a resource with the same name and path that you are attempting to use.

Instead of force-unwrapping, I would suggest something like this:

```
class var urlofModelInThisBundle : URL f
let bundle = Bundle(for: self)
if let resource = bundle.url(forResource: "XrayValidator2", withExtension:"mlmodelc") {
    return resource
}
else {
    Print("ERR: attempted to use a resource that was not found")
    return nil
}
```

You can control-click on your resource names, choose "Reveal in finder" to verify the full names of your resources.

EDIT:

To list all files in the bundle run this and please paste the output into your question:

```
let paths = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "mlmodelc", inDirectory: nil)
print(paths)
```

If you don't have any results from that, try this:

```
let paths = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: "mlmodel", inDirectory: nil)
print(paths)
```

Comment: But this same thing works when I create a Xcode Project. But with Swift Playground App it causing error.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Also, it may work in your Xcode project, but force unwrapping is not a good practice.

Comment: I understand the fact that force unwrapping is not a good practise but this swift model file are auto generated. They are automatically added when we add the ML Model in our project.

Comment: I tried printing the paths but it was empty.

Comment: How can we add Model to the target in Swift Playgrounds? I think this might be the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U6I0.png